# Why is move_base taking shortcuts?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. In my simulations, my move_base is not properly following a path.
The **planner's plan** is being generated correctly, but when the robot starts to move, it is always trying to move to the final portion of my global plan.

For example, if my planner's path makes a turn around a corner, my robot tries to cut the corner straight to the final portion of my global plan, **instead of following** the generated path.

I tried to change move_base parameters as **simple attractor** or **heading_scoring**, but the behavior does not change.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27584/why-is-move_base-taking-shortcuts?/) by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4402 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe score of goal is higher than score of path.
Try set parameter goal_distance_bias = 0 or 0.1 for local planer.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-02-14**:
thanks, that actually helped at some extent. now the robot tries to stay on the path, but very frequently it stops and start rotating in place. this did not happen with the goal_distance_bias set at default value.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-14**:
Now try to increase goal_distance_bias until the desired result

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-02-21**:
it is hard to find a balance between rotating in place and following the global path. I also found problems with my simulated laser (had the wrong topic name), that would explain some of the problems I was having, as not inflating local obstacles, which resulted in robot crashing on walls. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try following [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) tutorial. It will help you with setting all of the parameters for navigation.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-02-14**:
I will check it out. thanks